# why is my subview view wont follow constraints using autolayout in interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, autolayout

Let say I have MainView(red) has a subview which is UITextView and UIView(green), I want all subviews width same as superview. I add some constraints add it works EXCEPT the UIView(green). this is how I do it, please see below..

By default MainView has a 320 width..
[image]

But when I try to change the width of the MainView to 500, UIView(green) won't follow the constraints, unlike the uitextview.
[image]

when I click the warning (yellow arrow)
this shows the warning constraints of the UIView(subview) only, but how come no warning for UITextView is there any constrains or settings that I missed on that view? 
[image]

**Edit:**
Constrains of UIView (green)

[image]

Comment: Select the green subview in IB. Post a screenshot of the constraint information in its Size Inspector.

Comment: @bilobatum see the edited. tnx

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when frames get out of sync with the constraints. You may be able to remedy this if you select the view and then click on the "Resolve Autolayout Issues" button, [image], and choose "Update All Frames In View" (if you were using storyboard, that option is called "Update All Frames In View Controller). It should update the frames to match the constraints. Then subsequent changes to the red view's width should update the green view, too.

Comment: Hi, This is correct, But in my issue, I already set all the constrains, and I can see no update frames option.

Comment: @Bordz Don't see it when you tap that "Resolve Autolayout Issues" button? Or is it there, but just grayed out? Occasionally, I find I have to deselect the view I'm working on (i.e. tap on the background of IB workspace) and then re-select the view I'm working on. BTW, what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: xcode 5, its greyed out. I think there nothing I can do on that option, cuz I set all the constrains correctly? (I guess) hehehe

Comment: @Bordz You might want to manually adjust the frame of the green view (nudging it out of sync with the constraints), and then the "update all frames" option should be enabled. BTW, if Xcode is acting weird, (sadly) quitting Xcode and reopening the project is always a good thing to do.

Comment: I try to nudge it out, and update the frames, reopen,clean the xcode, still nothing happens. thank you BTW.

Comment: @Bordz Good luck hunting this down. BTW, the "Resolve Autolayout Issues" button is only enabled when you select the view, so that's one final thing to check out. If you want to upload your project somewhere (github, dropbox, etc.) and share that link here, I'm happy to take a look at this view, if you want.